# Getting the accent color from primary color dynamically using CSS or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, sass, colors

I am making a small color converter application that changes background colour dynamically based on converted color. The problem is, I cannot define colors used for UI elements like fonts, input borders, etc. If user selects the same color to convert - all UI will dissapear completely.

I had the idea to use css filter property maybe, brightness would be nice. But, I could not handle it with borders and so on.

The present bg-color is stored in css-variable.

The question is, how is it possible to get accent color from any color suing CSS or JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution and I would like to leave it here.

1. By using SASS, the problem could be solved quite easily with such SASS color functions. For my problem the **mix($color1, $color2, $weight: 50%)** function would be the perfect choise. Alas, I could use only pure CSS.
2. Trying to do something similar, I have written a function that mixes color with some amount of white or black, depending on color brightness. Brightness is calculated from RGB value; mixing is done with hex value of the same color.

```
const accentColour = (rgb, hex) => {

  const rgbLightness = (r, g, b) => 0.2126 * r + 0.587 * g + 0.114 * b;

  const blendColours = (hex1, hex2, amount) => {
    // remove "#"
    [ hex1, hex2 ] = [ parseInt(hex1.slice(1), 16), parseInt(hex2.slice(1), 16) ];
    const [ hex1_12 , hex2_12 ] = [ hex1 >> 16 , hex2 >> 16 ];
    const [ hex1_34, hex2_34 ] = [ hex1 >> 8 & 255, hex2 >> 8 & 255 ];
    const [ hex1_56, hex2_56 ] = [ 255 & hex1, 255 & hex2 ];
    // return "#" + (16777216 + 65536 * (Math.round((hex2_12 - hex1_12) * amount) + hex1_12) + 256 * (Math.round((hex2_34 - hex1_34) * amount) + hex1_34) + (Math.round((hex2_56 - hex1_56) * amount) + hex1_56)).toString(16).slice(1);

    return "#" + [
      16777216,
      65536 * (Math.round((hex2_12 - hex1_12) * amount) + hex1_12),
      256 * (Math.round((hex2_34 - hex1_34) * amount) + hex1_34),
      (Math.round((hex2_56 - hex1_56) * amount) + hex1_56),
    ]
      .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
      .toString(16)
      .slice(1);
  };

  return (
    (rgbLightness(...rgb) < 180)
      ? blendColours(hex, "#FFFFFF", 0.75)
      : blendColours(hex, "#000000", 0.5)
  );  
};
```

Comment: Can you please explain the fixed values (0.2126, 0.587, 0.114, 8, 16777216, 65536, 256, 0.5, 0.75, 180)